# Mac OSX + Eclipse + Subclipse + SMB - Not able to commit files

Tags: eclipse, svn, macos, subclipse, rhel5

I use Eclipse+Subclipse on my Mac to edit a code base that resides on a RHEL5 desktop, via an SMB share connection. Everything works like a charm, except the SVN commit part. A JavaHL exception is thrown on commit, that looks like the following.

`org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Operation not permitted
svn: Can't move '/Volumes/share1/some/deep/nested/folder/in/project/.svn/tmp/entries' to '/Volumes/share1/some/deep/nested/folder/in/project/.svn/entries': Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the SMB user and of the files/directories on your working directory.

Comment: Well, that was my first try, but didn't work. I tried the changing uchg (user immutable) flag as well, but no luck. Looks like some issue with the JavaHL adapter.

I resolved by changing the adapter to Pure Java (SVNKit) instead of JavaHL. That seems to fix the problem. Thanks for the answer anyway!